# private and public functions

Tags: c++, class, oop, coding-style

I'm trying to teach myself about classes in C++, and I'm running into a bit of a stumbling block, which I can't seem to clear up. I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the correct direction.

I decided to construct a small `Tree` class, which constructs a new BST. I want to be able to call certain methods on my object like so:

```
int main() {
  Tree<int> tree1;

  tree1.insert(5);

  int treeMin = tree1.minValue();
  int treeMax = tree1.maxValue();

  tree1.printTree();
}
```

Right now, in order to call these functions, I am defining both `public` and `private` functions so that you don't call function in a redundant manner. for instance:

(what I'm trying to avoid)

```
int main() {
  Tree<int> tree1;

  tree1.insert(tree1, 5);

  int treeMin = tree1.minValue(tree1);
  int treeMax = tree1.maxValue(tree1);

  tree1.printTree(tree1);
}
```

In order to do avoid having this redundancy, I am defining a public and private version of the same function. In this way, the public functions call their private counterparts.

```
template<class T>
class Tree {
private:
  treeNode<T>* root;
  treeNode<T>* newNode(T data);
  void insert(treeNode<T>*& root, T data);
  int minValue(treeNode<T>*& root);
  int maxValue(treeNode<T>*& root);
  void printTree(treeNode<T>*& root);

public:
  Tree();
  ~Tree();
  void insert(T data);
  int minValue();
  int maxValue();
  void printTree();
};
```

And then, as an example:

```
template<class T>
int Tree<T>::minValue() { minValue(root); }

template<class T>
int Tree<T>::minValue(treeNode<T>*& root) {
  if (root == NULL) { return 0; }
  if (root->left == NULL) { return root->data; }
  else { minValue(root->left); }
}
```

So, my question is:
If I'm writing my functions recursively, I understand that I need to declare a private function that accepts an argument, but is this considered a bad style? Is this sloppy?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CaptainObvlious So this is the right way to go about it? I know this isn't a full BST class, I just want to make sure the public/private interface is the right way to go about it, and that it doesn't look absolutely ridiculous to a more seasoned programmer. (thanks! :)

Comment: A tree is a complex structure, there is not a "one way" to do it. You are being defensive about what is being made public, that is a good thing.  If this fills your needs, you are on the right way.

Comment: The problem you present (needing to send a reference to the object to one of its own member functions) doesn't exist, and certainly isn't fixed by duplicating public member functions as private member functions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure I understand. If I just made the private functions public, wouldn't I necessarily have to pass the object to the member function since I've defined the member function's operations recursively? If I don't pass the object, then there is no way to go through the recursion. Please forgive me if this is completely incorrect and idiotic.

Comment: No private/public has nothing to do with this; and passing a "this is me" reference/pointer into a _member_ function is completely incorrect and idiotic. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ack, sorry, I know I'm being slow. I get that it's stupid, which is why I was trying to make it look like you weren't passing a reference to the object itself by somehow "hiding" the real operations of the member function. I know that whole thing sounds stupid, but I don't know how I would otherwise call the member function if it depended on the object for it's recursion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `private` member functions in your code are only a needless complication. I would just move their code to the public member functions: less code, more clean code, less indirection so more directly grokable code, all nice. For some of them you *might* support reuse by making them free functions in a `details` namespace, but I think that would be premature generalization, expending effort on possible reuse that probably won't take place.

Example code at end of answer.

---

Re another design issue, declaring

```
int minValue();
int maxValue();
```

precludes calling these member functions on a `const` object. Instead do

```
int minValue() const;
int maxValue() const;
```

---

A third issue, it's generally a Really Bad Idea™ to do i/o in a non-i/o class. If you print the tree to standard output, how would you use the class in a GUI program? So, instead of

```
void printTree();
```

do e.g.

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream& stream ) const;
```

or e.g.

```
string toString() const;
```

---

A fourth issue, you need to *take charge of copying* – read up on the “rule of three” and the “rule of zero”.

The simplest way to do that is to replace

```
treeNode<T>* root;
```

with

```
unique_ptr< treeNode< T > > root;
```

where `unique_ptr` is `std::unique_ptr`.

Alternatively declare at least a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, or inherit from a “non-copyable” class. To make the class effectively non-copyable, you can make these operators `private` or `protected`. To make it copyable, make them `public` and do the right thing in each (a good default implementation of the copy assignment operator is to express it in terms of copy construction via the copy-and-swap idiom, which means introducing a non-throwing `swap` function).

---

A fifth issue is that the implementation

```
template<class T>
int Tree<T>::minValue(treeNode<T>*& root) {
  if (root == NULL) { return 0; }
  if (root->left == NULL) { return root->data; }
  else { minValue(root->left); }
}
```

strongly suggests that each node stores a value that's implicitly convertible to `int`. You don't provide the declaration of `treeNode`. But this looks like a design level bug, that the intent was for `minValue` to return a `T`, not an `int` – and ditto for `maxValue`.

---

A very small coding issue (not design level): in C++11 and later you should preferentially use `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

- `nullptr` can be freely passed through argument forwarding functions, while `NULL` then suffers a decay to integral type, since `NULL` is just a zero-constant of integral type.
- `nullptr` does not require that you include any header, while `NULL` is defined by a header, i.e. with `nullptr` you avoid a header dependency.

---

Finally, regarding

```
if (root == NULL) { return 0; }
```

for the `minValue`, this may of course be the intention, the design. But possibly you want to either signal failure or treat the call as a logic error.

- To treat the call as an error, `assert( root != nullptr );` and provide a means for the client code to check for empty tree.
- To signal failure, either return an object with optional value (e.g. like `boost::optional` or Barton/Nackmann's original `Fallible`), or throw an exception (the `std::runtime_error` class is a good general default exception class choice).
- It's also possible to combine the two approaches, to provide both, perhaps with names like `minValue` and `minValueOrX`.

More generally it's sometimes possible to reserve some special value as a "no such" indicator. E.g. `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()`. But this makes for brittle code, since such a value can easily occur naturally in the data, and since client code may easily fail to check for the special value.

---

Example, coded for C++11:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::endl
#include <string>       // std::string

namespace my {
    using std::string;

    template<class T>
    class Tree
    {
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            T       value;
            Node*   p_left;
            Node*   p_right;

            auto to_string() const -> string
            {
                using std::to_string;
                string const left   = (p_left == nullptr? "" : p_left->to_string());
                string const right  = (p_right == nullptr? "" : p_right->to_string());
                return "(" + left + " " + to_string( value ) + " " + right + ")";
            }

            ~Node() { delete p_left; delete p_right; }
        };

        Node*   root_;

        Tree( Tree const&  ) = delete;
        Tree& operator=( Tree const& ) = delete;

    public:
        auto is_empty() const -> bool { return (root_ == nullptr); }

        void insert( T const data )
        {
            Node** pp = &root_;
            while( *pp != nullptr )
            {
                auto const p = *pp;
                pp = (data < p->value? &p->p_left : &p->p_right);
            }
            *pp = new Node{ data, nullptr, nullptr };
        }

        auto minValue() const -> T
        {
            assert( root_ != nullptr );
            Node* p = root_;
            while( p->p_left != nullptr ) { p = p->p_left; }
            return p->value;
        }

        auto maxValue() const -> T
        {
            assert( root_ != nullptr );
            Node* p = root_;
            while( p->p_right != nullptr ) { p = p->p_right; }
            return p->value;
        }

        auto to_string() const -> string
        {
            return (root_ == nullptr? "" : root_->to_string());
        }

        ~Tree() { delete root_; }

        Tree(): root_( nullptr ) {}

        Tree( Tree&& other ): root_( other.root_ ) { other.root_ = nullptr; }
    };

}  // namespace my

auto main() -> int
{
    my::Tree<int> tree;
    for( int const x : {5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 1, 8} )
    {
        tree.insert( x );
    }

    using std::cout; using std::endl;
    cout << tree.to_string() << endl;
    cout << "min = " << tree.minValue() << ", max = " << tree.maxValue() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
(((( 1 ) 2 ) 3 ( 4 )) 5 (( 6 ) 7 ( 8 )))
min = 1, max = 8
```

Comment: @Alf Thank you. This has give me quite a lot to read up on! Much appreciated.

Comment: @New: I suddenly got afraid that my advice could be wrong, so I coded up an example. The only problem turned out to be `to_string`. The implementation above is simple but not optimally efficient in big-O terms.

Comment: Oh, and about recursive functions: if you need to recurse down the tree, then for the example code above you can do that via member functions in `Node` class, as illustrated for `to_string`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've been very helpful, and you've given me some excellent study material to go devour :) Thanks!